# Adding a root view with an explicit id already set?

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to add a root view with an explicit id already set. React Native uses the id field to track react tags and will overwrite this field.

The following error occurred while making a redux form, but I do not know how to solve it.

[image: error message]

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790035/react-native-error-message-trying-to-add-a-root-view-with-an-explicit-id-alread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native error message: Trying to add a root view with an explicit id already set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790035/react-native-error-message-trying-to-add-a-root-view-with-an-explicit-id-alread)